# Using LEFT JOIN inside datatable server side script

Tags: jquery, mysql, datatable, left-join

dear all, i'll take some data from the database.
and join two tables.the code like:

```
SELECT DATE(A.Inspection_datetime) AS Date, 
  A.Model, 
  COUNT(A.Serial_number) AS Qty, 
  B.Name 
FROM inspection_report AS A 
LEFT JOIN Employee AS B ON A.NIK = B.NIK 
 GROUP BY A.Model, A.Serial_number
```

i want show this data using jQuery [dataTable](http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/server_side.html).I have tried to modify at dataTable's server side script.I have changed at this part:

```
$sWhere = " WHERE Inspection_datetime LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['sSearch'] )."%' 
  OR Model LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['sSearch'] )."%' 
  OR Serial_number LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['sSearch'] )."%' 
  OR NIK LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['sSearch'] )."%' ";

$sQuery = "SELECT id, 
  DATE(A.Inspection_datetime) AS Date, 
  A.Model, 
  COUNT(A.Serial_number) AS Qty, 
  B.Name 
  FROM inspection_report AS A 
  LEFT JOIN Employee AS B ON A.NIK = B.NIK .$sWhere.$sOrder.$sLimit";

$sOutput .= "[";
  $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['id']).'",';
  $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['Date']).'",';
  $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['Model']).'",';
  $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['Qty']).'",';
  $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['Name']).'"';
  $sOutput .= "],";
```

i want the result like my mysql code, but this make like:

```
{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":2,"iTotalDisplayRecords":2, "aaData":[["42","","bar","","Steve"]]}
```

Comment: Your query & expected output don't appear to match - how do id, date, model, qty and name turn into "sEcho":1/etc?  Also are both the tables MyISAM?

Comment: i'm just trying the mysql code and can work..and still try to modified datatable's script and as you can see the result not good.what is the better way for the first step?

Comment: what I need now is how to display two more parts like date and qty?

Comment: thanks for kiamlalluno who has edited my question.=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what have I done? I was very careless. these are to be replaced.

```
$sOutput .= "[";
                $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['id']).'",';
                $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['Date').'",';
                $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['Model']).'",';
                $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['Qty']).'",';
                $sOutput .= '"'.addslashes($aRow['Name']).'"';
                $sOutput .= "],";
```